# go1.16 sigs.k8s.io/json sf.IsExported undefined error

Tags: json, go, go-modules

When I build the Go project I get the following error

```
# sigs.k8s.io/json/internal/golang/encoding/json
../pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/json@v0.0.0-20211020170558-c049b76a60c6/internal/golang/encoding/json/encode.go:1249:12: sf.IsExported undefined (type reflect.StructField has no field or method IsExported)
../pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/json@v0.0.0-20211020170558-c049b76a60c6/internal/golang/encoding/json/encode.go:1255:18: sf.IsExported undefined (type reflect.StructField has no field or method IsExported)
```

I know this is a *version problem*, and it can be solved by upgrading the version to 1.17, but because the company's environment is 1.16, **it cannot be upgraded because of this project**

How can I modify it, if I lower the lower version, which version should I lower to?

I really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this error could be coming from kubebuilder (or a tool derived from it such as operator-sdk). Then you should use the correct version of the given tool. E.g.,

- kubebuilder - have a list mapping go versions to kubebuilder versions https://book.kubebuilder.io/quick-start.html#prerequisites
- operator-sdk - don't have a list, but you can find it by going through the documentation for each version, e.g., the first I found that has a version lower than 1.17 is https://v1-16-x.sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/installation/#prerequisites-1